# 12296#0: *4 --passenger runs but page does not display -- Rails by example Sample App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Why are the apache files the only things showing up.  Why isn't passengers page appearing?

What is making it point to public/public?
I did delete the index.html file because i have a static_pages controller

```
12296#0: *4 "/var/www/sample_app/releases/20120522195731/public/public/index.html" is not found 
(2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server:
```

This is what appears when i go to url

```
Index of /
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[TXT]   404.html    22-May-2012 19:57   728      
[TXT]   422.html    22-May-2012 19:57   711      
[TXT]   500.html    22-May-2012 19:57   643      
[IMG]   favicon.ico 22-May-2012 19:57   0    
[ ] passenger.3000.log  22-May-2012 21:35   488      
[ ] passenger.3000.pid.lock 22-May-2012 21:36   0    
[TXT]   robots.txt  22-May-2012 19:57   204
```

Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at server.silvernightfall.com Port 80

I edited the apache2.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12  
/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

And I edited the apache2/sites-available/server

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin victoria@jbyte.com
ServerName server.silvernightfall.com
# ServerAlias
DocumentRoot /var/www/sample_app/current/public
ErrorLog /var/www/sample_app/error.log
RailsEnv production
<Directory "/var/www/sample_app/current/public">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

static pages controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

And a routes pages

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => 'static_pages#home'

 match '/signup',           to: 'users#new'

 match '/help',         to: 'static_pages#help'
 match '/about',        to: 'static_pages#about'
 match '/contact',          to: 'static_pages#contact'


end
```

The only other thing I think could be messing it up is the deploy.rb

```
                            # The name of your app
            set :application, "sample_app"

            # The directory on the EC2 node that will be deployed to
            set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"

            set :keep_releases, 3

            # deploy with git
            set :scm, :git
            set :repository,  "git@github.com:SilverNightFall/sample_app.git"
            set :git_shallow_clone, 1
            set :branch, "master"
            set :use_sudo, true

            # gets ssh info
            set :user, "ubuntu"
            ssh_options[:keys] = ["/Users/Victoria/Documents/ServerKeys/key.pem"]
            ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
            default_run_options[:pty] = true

            # The address of the remote host on EC2 (the Public DNS address)
            set :location, "server.silvernightfall.com"

            # setup some Capistrano roles
            role :app, location
            role :web, location
            role :db,  location, :primary => true

            after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_db'

            namespace :deploy do

              desc "Restart Application"
              task :restart, :roles => :app do
                   run "touch #{deploy_to}/#{shared_dir}/tmp/restart.txt"
              end

              desc "Symlinks the database.yml"
              task :symlink_db, :roles => :app do
              run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml    
                              #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
              end
```

Comment: Hi, Not the answer but a cleanup suggestion: `run "touch #{deploy_to}/#{shared_dir}/tmp/restart.txt"` can also be written as `run "touch #{shared_path}/tmp/restart.txt"` so you can also replace `#{deploy_to}/shared` with `#{shared_path}` as well.

Comment: Also, the restart command should be run in the `current_path` not the `shared_path` (in case you don't trust your symlinks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to uninstall and reinstall Passenger.  It looks like it was installed twice.

Comment: ah .. the old "re-install from scratch to debug trick!" .. Thanks for posting your solution.